# Why converting to integer first when converting from any type except string to float?

Tags: php, floating-point, integer, int, type-conversion

> For information on converting [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to [float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), see [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). For values of other types, the conversion is performed by converting the value to [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) first and then to float.
>
> http://php.net/float

Why it is needed to convert into integer type first, and then into float type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a string could feasibly contain a float-like value. Or what is the floating point value of an `array()`? Or of a `resource`? As such, the rules for converting to `int` are applied to such values, because those rules already exist and are defined. No need to repeat those conversion rules for all types for floats; simply apply `int` rules and then cast to `float`.